# React's design philosophy: Why update child-components when props haven't changed?

Tags: reactjs, design-patterns

As we know, when a node changes, every child component is automatically re-rendered; even if their props remain the same.

It's possible to design around this by using `shouldComponentUpdate, PureComponent or React.memo`.

However, I'm curious, why is it necessary to re-render by default? I can't think of an instance where if a child component's props are identical, that it'll need to be re-rendered. Though perhaps I'm missing something...

Comment: Functions are not pure by default. Just because props do not change does not mean that the render result will be the same. This is why we can optionally specify that a component is pure.

Comment: I assume you mean something like having `Math.random()` in a function? I guess you're right... though it would seem more intuitive to me to have users specify an unpure function, rather than the other way around. Given I'd assume most react functions are pure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> even if their props remain the same

Therein lies the rub.  *Proving* the props are the same is nontrivial.  Let's take objects `A` and `B`, both of which stringify to a Meg of JSON: how do you check they're equal without deeply comparing?

Using referential equality is not sufficient (because in-place mutations exist) and shallow comparisons (*a la* `PureComponent`) are not always sufficient because they're, well, shallow.  Thus, we have to opt in to these behaviors.